# Mostrar tabela html formata no corpo do e-mail no envio

Tags: php

Estou tentando mostrar no corpo do e-mail uma tabela html com os produtos orçados pelo cliente, mas ela está indo todo desconfigurada.

O que estou fazendo no envio é isso:

```html
$data_pedido = date("d-m-Y");
$hora = date("H:i:s");
$mostradata = substr($data_pedido,8,2).'/'.substr($data_pedido,5,2).'/'.substr($data_pedido,0,4); 
$assunto = "Orçamento";
// E-MAIL DO EMITENTE 
$auxRemetente = "email@cliente";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1". PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1". PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "From: $auxRemetente". PHP_EOL; // remetente
$headers .= "Cc: $auxRemetente". PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Return-Path: $email". PHP_EOL; // return-path 
// CONFIGURAÇÃO DO CORPO DO E-MAIL
$message = " 
Orçamento\n
Data - $mostradata - Hora - $hora\r
Nome - $nome\r
CPF/CNPJ - $cpfcnpj\r
Empresa - $empresa\r
Telefone - $telefone\r
E-mail - $email\r
Mensagem - $observacao\r"; 
$message .= '
<table width="1000" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin:0 auto;border-collapse:collapse;">
   <tr>
      <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="background:#A71930;color:#FFF;font-weight:bold;border:0px solid #FFFFFF" height="32">
      <td colspan="5" style="font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial; font-size: 13px; color: #FFF; padding-left:10px">
      PRODUTOS</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="border-bottom:1px dashed #9f9f9f;background-color:#e1e1e1; font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial; font-size: 15px; color: #9f9f9f">
      <td style="padding: 10px 0" align="center">ID</td>
      <td style="padding: 10px 0">Nome</td>
      <td style="padding: 10px 0" align="center">Quantidade</td>
   </tr>
   '; 
   $itens = count($_POST["itens"]);
   $NumItens = $itens;
   for($i=1;$i<=$NumItens;$i++) {
   $ProdID =  $_POST["item_id_{$i}"]; 
   $ProdDescricao = $_POST["item_descr_{$i}"]; 
   if ( isset($_SESSION["quantidade"][$ProdID]) && ($_SESSION["quantidade"][$ProdID] != 0) ){
   $ProdQuantidade = $_SESSION["quantidade"][$ProdID];
   }else{
   $ProdQuantidade = 1;
   }
   $message .= '
   <tr>
      <td style="padding: 10px; font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial; font-size: 15px; color: #000" align="center">'.$ProdID.'</td>
      <td style="padding: 0px; font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial; font-size: 15px; color: #000" align="left">'.$ProdDescricao.'</td>
      <td style="padding: 10px; font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial; font-size: 15px; color: #000" align="center"">'.$ProdQuantidade.'</td>
   </tr>
   ';          
   }
   $message .= '
</table>
';
// ENVIO DA MENSAGEM
mail($email, $assunto, $message, $headers, "-f$auxRemetente");
```

O que está sendo enviado:

```html
Data - 17/-2/15-0 - Hora - 15:27:04
Nome - Valter Ferreira Martins
CPF/CNPJ - 635.507.769-34
Empresa - Topdeia
Telefone - 4432333725
E-mail - email@gmail.com
Mensagem - Nada
<table width="1000" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin:0 auto;border-collapse:collapse;">
   <tr>
      <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="background:#A71930;color:#FFF;font-weight:bold;border:0px solid #FFFFFF" height="32">
      <td colspan="5" style="font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial; font-size: 13px; color: #FFF; padding-left:10px">
      PRODUTOS</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="border-bottom:1px dashed #9f9f9f;background-color:#e1e1e1; font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial; font-size: 15px; color: #9f9f9f">
      <td style="padding: 10px 0" align="center">ID</td>
      <td style="padding: 10px 0">Nome</td>
      <td style="padding: 10px 0" align="center">Quantidade</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="padding: 10px; font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial; font-size: 15px; color: #000" align="center">1209</td>
      <td style="padding: 0px; font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial; font-size: 15px; color: #000" align="left">BALAN�A ASA DELTA DA CARRETA P/ PINO � 61,5mm</td>
      <td style="padding: 10px; font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial; font-size: 15px; color: #000" align="center"">78</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="padding: 10px; font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial; font-size: 15px; color: #000" align="center">1219</td>
      <td style="padding: 0px; font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial; font-size: 15px; color: #000" align="left">SUPORTE CENTRAL DO TRUCK</td>
      <td style="padding: 10px; font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial; font-size: 15px; color: #000" align="center"">78</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tenta usar <br/> para quebra de linha

Comment: Você tinha que ter deixado Content-type: text/plain na pergunta para dar sentido a resposta :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Para enviar um email em formato HTML, basta informar que o mesmo é do tipo `text/html`

Nesta linha

`$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1". PHP_EOL;`

Tem que ser

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1". PHP_EOL;
```

Exemplos:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo "<b>adventistapr</b>";
// saida: <b>adventistapr</b>

header("Content-Type: text/html");
echo "<b>adventistapr</b>";
// saida: adventistapr
```

Comment: Olá @Leo Caracciolo, obrigado pela dica, mas agora a tabela aparece mas o texto antes dele fica em uma linha, sem quebra.

Comment: coloca o popular <br>

Comment: agora deu certo, valeu pelas duas dicas.